# What is "Roid damage"?

Tags: borderlands-2

I got a shield which noticed "increased roid damage" as a stat. What exactly is "roid damage"? I assume it's melee attacks (steroids) but for all I know it's specific to some other classes' ability.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Roid damage increases melee damage, [though apparently only when the shield is depleted](http://www.bl2wiki.com/Shield).  Not class specific, though.